# Weblogic server startup is slow

Tags: java, weblogic

We have added the parameter

```
    -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLOutputFactoryImpl  
    -Djavax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory=com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl
```

to JAVA_OPTIONS in setDomainEnv.sh file of weblogic server. this parameter was added for a project requirement.
After this the server startup is slow by 5 times.I couldnt find any info in logs. 
Could anybody suggest me over this problem

Comment: This migh be something else. Can you try to remove the parameters above and see if startup time improves?

Comment: Also, is your application doing anything like talking to external web services at startup?

Comment: yes.. removing the parameter improves the startup time a lot. we dont use any webservices at startup

Answer (score 0):

Given what you told me, I recommend to do the following:

Step 1:

Start with the slow configuration on and start taking thread dumps let say every 30 seconds until the server is up. Check the log and look for a) What threads in RUNNABLE state are doing b) If there are blocked threads with suspicious stack traces such as having those 'com.sun.xml.internal' in them.

You can take thread dumps by sending 'kill -3 '

Step 2.

If the Step 1 didn't help, start up the system under a profiler such as JProfiler while enabling CPU and thread recording at startup and see if there are any obvious CPU hot spots or thread blocking.

That should cover it.

Hope this helps,

Slava Imeshev